# Once I upgrade from an IPhone 3G what should I do with it?

Tags: iphone, mobile

My iPhone 3G is already slow and starting to be unusable.  Pretty soon I am going to upgrade my main phone.  However, it is such a shame to put it in my gadget drawer to collect dust.  Do you have any interesting ideas of what to do with this old device?

Comment: I vote for "paperweight" or "landfill". The destiny of all trashy, here-today-gone-tomorrow consumer tech. Also, this is the wrong site to post this question on.

Comment: This isn't a programming or programming-related topic.

Comment: I am looking for ideas which I hope include a programming related idea.

Answer (score 1):

If your doing development work, you should keep it to test your code on old devices. Users don't upgrade expensive devices like iPhones as quick as they do less capable mobile devices. You'd be surprised on much of the market runs on old hardware. It's important to test new apps on old hardware to see if they work so you can at least warn customers that the app requires minimum hardware.

Answer (score 0):

See if it runs snow leopard or even Phone 7.